# How to find the equilibrium of differential equation model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Continuous population model, with the following equation model:
$$\frac{\mathrm dN}{\mathrm dt}=rN\left(1-\frac Nk\right)-\frac{aN}{b+N}.$$
To find the equilibrium I make the equation equal to $0$. Then, do I rearrange it to get $N$ on its own?

Comment: @Larry yea its! Aren't you missing a bk term in the last equation?

Comment: Right, I will make the correction. Since my solution suits your question, I am going make the comment an answer.

Comment: Yes, its! What sort of parameters could a and b be?

Comment: I am not really sure, I think the equation represents a predator-prey model.

Comment: @Larry I was thinking a logistic model with harvesting?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution is $N=0$

To find other equilibrium points, we can do the following:
$$0 = rN\left(1-\frac{N}{k}\right)-\frac{aN}{b+N}$$
$$\frac{a}{b+N}=r\left(1-\frac{N}{k}\right)$$
$$\frac{a}{b+N}=r\left(\frac{k-N}{k}\right)$$
$$\frac{ak}{r} = (b+N)(k-N)$$
$$N^2-(k-b)N+\frac{ak}{r}-bk = 0$$
Solve the quadratic equation to get the solutions for $N$.